# Automapper Constructor Parameters

Tags: automapper-2

I've just started using this and immediately ran into a problem mapping a parameter to a a constructor parameter.

I've tried every example I can find on SO but none seem to work and the documentation doesn't mention this feature as far as I can see.

The examples show:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserProfile, UserProfileModel>().ConstructUsing(x => new UserProfileModel(x.Id);
```

I can't figure out the syntax to get access to the Id property on the UserProfile object.

Another example shows:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TypeOneDto, TypeOne>().ConstructUsing((Func<ResolutionContext, TypeOne>) (r => new TypeOne()));
```

On using any of these lambdas I just have access to the ResolutionContext not the parent object?

Any Ideas?

Comment: I've got the mapping working now but this blows up doing two way mapping ...

    Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<UserProfile, UserProfileModel>());
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<UserProfileModel, UserProfile>());

How do you configure two way mapping?

Comment: Did you manage to sort this out? FYI - I would use profiles as described [here](http://blog.velir.com/index.php/2012/08/27/organizing-automappers-map-configurations-in-mvc/).

Comment: I actually changed my implementation so I didn't need it in the end but this info is very useful, thanks.